# How can i make this simple program work in C?

Tags: c

I want to print out all numbers between 100,000 and 100 with the same digits reversed as fraction.
eg.
100.001

101.101

102.201

103.301

104.401
...
...

243.342
...
12345.54321

I dont know how to do this, so first I tried to make a simpler program to print out with the same fraction:
eg.

100.100

12345.12345

243.243

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double number, a, b, c, d;

    for (number=100000; number>99; number--){
   // printf("%f ", number);

        if (number==100000){
            a = number/100000000000;
            printf("%f ", number+a);
    }
else
    if (number < 100000 && number > 9999){
        b = number/100000;
        printf("%f ", number+b);
    }
else
    if (number > 999 && number < 10000) {
        c= number / 10000;
         printf("%f ", number+c);
    }
else
     if (number > 99 && number <1000) {
        d= number/ 1000;
         printf("%f ", number+d);
    }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea how to reverse the fraction digits, so i would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Not sure... do you want to print all *real* numbers between the two? You know there is a *continuum* of these, right?

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). See http://floating-point-gui.de/ ; use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop...

Comment: Maybe re-think your approach and use *strings*? Like `"bar.rab"`, `"foo.oof"`... `"125.521"`

Comment: @EugeneSh. He's just iterating over integers, and then adding the reverse of the integer as a fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you're just looking for something like:

```
void                                                                               
print_num(int i)                                                                   
{                                                                                  
        char buf[32];                                                              
        char rev[32];                                                              
        int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", i);                                
        for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){                                              
                rev[n - j - 1] = buf[j];                                           
        }                                                                          
        printf("%s.%s\n", buf, rev);                                               
}
```

Comment: Can i ask where to copy this code? I tried everything i could, but it doesnt work for me :S

Comment: Copy the above function into your file just before: `int main(void){ for(int i = 100; i < 100000; i++) print_num(i); return 0; }`